# Set number of reducers in Hive streaming query

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata

I have a problem with setting number of reducers in streaming job.

query looks like this:

```
set mapred.job.name = 'Job name';
set mapred.reduce.tasks=128;
FROM (
  FROM (
    SELECT id, record, day
    FROM table_X TABLESAMPLE (BUCKET 1 OUT OF 4 ON id) 
    WHERE DAY='2015-08-27'
    CLUSTER BY(id)
  ) temp_table
  REDUCE *
  USING 'python script.py' AS id, decision
) t
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_Y
  SELECT *;
```

I want to reduce records in table_X using python script. It is a computationally intensive task and it is also crucial that records are being clustered by reducers.

The problem is I cannot balance load by setting large number of reducers.

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks:
```

doesn't work at all, it gives me 128 reducers but at the end there is 1 reducer left, job is at 99.9% and it works very long (my guess all work - streaming through script is left to this reducer)

```
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer:
```

somewhat helps, but I cannot balance load well enough. It still gives me ~100 reducers but at the end there is 20-30 reducers work on streaming through script. Btw can someone clarify: if I set it to 1000000 bytes = 1Mb, do we talk about compressed volume? How small this parameter can be?

What else can you recommend to set minimum amount of reducers?